# Vue is not mounting and getting no error messages

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I have created a project using vue-cli@4 and its working fine but I have done some changes in main.js and it is not working anymore.

```
//main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from './App.vue'

//Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#root-app",
  //commented components property when using render and mount
  components: {
    App
  },
  data: {
    name: "amandeep Singh"
  }
  // render: h => h(App),
}); //.$mount('#app')
```

App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    testingggg
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
}
</script>
```

Index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>admin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root-app">
        {{name}}
        <app></app>
    </div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It's showing nothing even "name" value is not interpolated.
But if I Uncomment

> render: h => h(App),

and

> .$mount('#app')

everything works fine.
So my question why does not it with these two commented. I have checked many examples and seen projects where they have not to use render function, all they have used is "el" property to mount vue to Html and everything works.

So someone can please what's happening here? What I am doing wrong?
How can I make work without render and mount and why it is necessary?

Comment: Update: Inspected the dom and observed that <div id="root-app"> gets removed from the HTML during runtime. Still confused about what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering the component you imported.

First, you imported the App.vue component which is the base holder of your components: `import App from './App.vue'`. Good!.

Next, You told Vue about the component you have imported so Vue knows about it (register): `components: { App },`. Good!

Now, what is left for you to do is to render the App.vue component. Do so by adding back the render function:

```
render: h => h(App),
```

Or like so:

```
template: "<App/>",
```

You should be good to go now.

Ref: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/29

Comment: But is it not required if you call component directly in the HTML?
Like "https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-todo-app-with-vue-dmqcl?fontsize=14", this working fine without template and render function